# Access Mac localhost from Windows parallels

Tags: network, windows, parallels-desktop

So there is a web appliance running on my Mac localhost. I want to check how it looks in Internet Explorer. I have Parallels Desktop 12 running Windows 10 with installed Parallels tools.

However, if I run IE in Coherence, it still cannot load localhost. I tried to set up IP of my mac to `10.0.0.45` (because I know my router gives IP in this range) and then accessing `http://10.0.0.45` from parallels IE

While this worked, I would like to know if there is better process to do that

Comment: localhost is the machine you are running on so in this case it is theBVM the MacOS is a different machine so you use an assigned IP address as you have done

Comment: I see. Currently in "overthinking everything" mode. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments above.

localhost is the machine you are running on (Mac) so the VM (windows) will need to point to the IP address of your machine.

For example:

If you are viewing your application on your Mac at:
http://localhost:8080/#/users

Now if your Mac ip is 10.1.0.2, the url to view on the windows VM will be:
http://10.1.0.2:8080/#/users